# Explicitly proving that the Hamiltonian is Lorentz covariant

Tags: terminology, physics, covariance, quantum-field-theory

I want to show explicitly that the Hamiltonian
$$
H = -\Omega V  +  \int d\tilde{\textbf{k}}\ \omega (a^\dagger(\textbf{k}) a(\textbf{k}) + b(\textbf{k}) b^\dagger(\textbf{k}) )
$$
 is Lorentz covariant. ($\Omega$ and $V$  are constants, $a$ and $b$ are the operators coming from the canonical quantization of the Klein Gordon equation, like what is done in (3.30) of Srednicki's book *Quantum Field Theory*). This made me realize my lack of understanding of Lorentz transformations:

I think that the definition of Lorentz invariance goes as follows: a certain object $A$ which depends on the spacetime coordinates $x$ is Lorentz invariant if $U(\Lambda)^{-1} A(x) U(\Lambda)= A(\Lambda^{-1}x)$ where $U$ is the appropriate representation of $\Lambda$ (it gives a map $U(\Lambda)$ that acts on the space to which $A$ belongs).

Now, can I state a similar definition for Lorentz covariance and use it to solve my problem?
I know that the derivative is Lorentz covariant:
$$
    \partial_{\mu'} = (\Lambda^{-1})^\nu_{\ \mu}\partial_\nu
$$

But a definition of the type "$A$ is Lorentz covariant if $A_{\mu'} = (\Lambda^{-1})^\nu_{\ \mu}A^\nu$" only makes sense if $A$ is a four component object, and that's not the case for the Hamiltonian. I wonder how one can state a definition of covariance for a more general case, maybe more on the lines of the definition of Lorentz invariance that I gave, and how to apply it to this case.

I am finding it hard to find a structured approach to Lorentz transformations. If you could help me untangle this a bit, that would be great.

Comment: The short answer is: a Hamiltonian is not Lorentz invariant. It is rather the time-component of the energy-momentum vector. I believe that the question is better suited for physics.SE.

Comment: @Fabian I thought about that, but I want to show it explicitly. Also, I would like to see a mathematical/formal discussion of this, if possible, that's why I posted here.